# Dynamic XPATH by for loop in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath, dynamic-testing

I'm trying to write dynamic XPATH by for loop in java selenium WebDriver but I couldn't do it.

There's a webpage and I have to print the string content which are in the xpaths mentioned in follow.

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/article[1]/header/div/div
```

**-> This is one of them and it's going like article[1], article[2], article[3] etc.**

First of all, I have to find how many articles are there and after getting the exact number, I can show the string contents regarding all article parameters by using for loop but I couldn't write it. Could you please support for my request?

Comment: Can you share the HTML source as formatted text?

Comment: Please share the HTML source or URL for the page. It helps in analyzing the elements in a page. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Your code would be cleaner if you use the Selenium API and search inside each element:

```
List<WebElement> articles = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/article"));

List<String> articlesText = articles.stream().map(
                                article -> 
                                return article.findElement(
                                   By.xpath("/header/div/div")).getText())
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```